# how to add a script value dynamically in html head tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to javaScript and html.
I am trying to create a script value dynamically and add to html head tag from java script and i am using angularjs also  as following..

my script.js

```
$http.get(URL).success(function (response) {
             $scope.trailers = response;
      var js = document.createElement('script');
      js.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
      js.value = "api_gallery = ["+trailers[0].youtubeId +", "+trailers[1].youtubeId +"];api_titles = ['video1', 'video2'];api_descriptions = ['description1', 'description2'];";

       document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
});
```

Actually the above code is for youtube videos popup.for that I have to assign the youtube urls to the above script.

and my details json is

```
[{"youtubeId": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eZh4R_6WtA"},{"youtubeId": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynDAZ8-xcSE"}]
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: A script element doesn't have `value` it has `innerHTML`

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-3-isolate-scope-and-function-parameters

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply.....I got it with your solutions also.....Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think js.value not work other all things ok.
use appendChild method to add your javascript code
below is example of add javascript code in head.

```
var txt = "alert('hello');";

var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");

// append it in a text node
scriptTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt));
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
```